# Total commander doesn't see Microsoft folder

Tags: windows-8.1, total-commander

I run total commander 8.51a with administrative rights and go to `c:\ProgramData\`.
I can't find folder `Microsoft`, then I go to Explorer and I see it there! I type `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\` in Total Commander manualy and it works! I try the same with `c:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\` and issue repeats. Is it Total Commander bug or is it something wrong with my settings?

Comment: You know what's strange, if you go to ProgramData via the command line then even `dir` fails to show that directory. `dir /a` shows it, but the directory is not hidden so why doesn't it show up with just `dir`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This folder is marked as "System folder", which can be seen when activating in Total Commander "Options -> Display -> Show system files". It is not hidden, but a system directory. As attributes of this folder it says "---s"...